# Finding Square Polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry, calculate-geometry

Anyone know of an ArcGIS tool (or trick!) to determine square polygons?

This is sort of a - find the geometric shape of a polygon, if all lines of a polygon are equidistant then YES (select)

Seems easy, yet .. .

Thoughts?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] which describes how the site works.  I think that this would be relatively straightforward to do using ArcPy so I think you should give that a try.  Alternatively, use the Field Calculator to get polygons with only four vertices and then convert your polygons to lines to check if all lines from same poly are same length.

Comment: ahh thanks for simplifying it for me. I think this may work.

Comment: The sides of a square  would only be equal in Cartesian coordinate reference; in a geographic coordinate reference you'd have to do a good deal more processing.

Comment: Further, a rhombus would meet the criteria for equal side lengths, but not square. You'll need to check the angles of the vertices. Perhaps compare the shape to the rotated bounding box of each polygon. All of this accounts for additional processing as per @Vince's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have shape area and length fields for your polygons, an SQL expression like

`(length / 4) * (length / 4) = area` or `POWER(length / 4, 2) = area` should select the polygons that are **perfectly** square.

You can introduce some error margin with something like

`POWER(length / 4, 2) < area + (area * 0.01)  AND POWER(length / 4, 2) > area - (area * 0.01)`, e.g. +/- 1% difference in area.